# Full outer join and Group By in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables (`trips` & `receipts`) which has a relationship, It's conflicated data relationship but I need to group them by FK and conditional based on time. In my book at the moment use full outer join since need to returns all fields for all rows with `where` clause in both that meet the join within conditions (FK & time).

Here are the requirements :

1. Select from two tables with a specific `run_date`
2. `source_id` as primary key of trip and `fk_id` as foriegn key of receipt
3. Full join two tables and select `receipts` as aggregate of array based on `created_at` of `receipt` within `trip` period (`pickup_time` and `drop_time`). The receipt still on the range of trip if `drop_time` of trip doesn't have a value (`null`)
4. Grouping the receipts if doesn't have trip data

```
WITH trips AS
(SELECT 1 source_id, 1 journey_id, timestamp("2022-7-16 21:22:12") pickup_time, timestamp("2022-07-16 22:07:50") drop_time, true is_continue_journey, "2022-07-19" run_date
UNION ALL SELECT 1, 12, timestamp("2022-07-16 22:07:50"), null, true, "2022-07-19"
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 2, timestamp("2022-7-18 06:12:02"), null, false, "2022-07-19"
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 3, timestamp("2022-7-19 12:00:01"), timestamp("2022-7-19 13:05:11"), true, "2022-07-26"
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 31, timestamp("2022-7-19 13:05:11"), timestamp("2022-7-19 14:25:17"), true, "2022-07-26"
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 32, timestamp("2022-7-19 14:25:17"),null, true, "2022-07-26"
UNION ALL SELECT 4, 4, timestamp("2022-7-24 08:35:01"), null, false, "2022-07-26"
UNION ALL SELECT 5, 5, timestamp("2022-7-25 10:24:01"), null, false, "2022-07-26"
UNION ALL SELECT 6, 6, timestamp("2022-7-25 12:18:39"), timestamp("2022-7-25 13:01:22"), true, "2022-07-26"
UNION ALL SELECT 6, 61, timestamp("2022-7-25 13:01:22"), null, true, "2022-07-26"
),
receipts AS
(SELECT 1 fk_id, 101 receipt_id, "printed" state, timestamp("2022-07-16 22:07:32") created_at, "2022-07-19" as run_date
  UNION ALL SELECT 1, 102, "printed", timestamp("2022-07-16 23:40:11"), "2022-07-19"
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 201, "printed", timestamp("2022-07-18 07:12:47"), "2022-07-19"
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 202, "printed", timestamp("2022-07-18 08:22:32"), "2022-07-19"
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 301, "printed", timestamp("2022-07-19 12:37:21"), "2022-07-26"
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 302, "printed", timestamp("2022-07-19 12:54:14"), "2022-07-26"
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 303, "printed", timestamp("2022-07-19 14:23:00"), "2022-07-26"
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 304, "printed", timestamp("2022-07-19 15:16:10"), "2022-07-26"
  UNION ALL SELECT 4, 401, "printed", timestamp("2022-07-24 09:15:47"), "2022-07-26"
  UNION ALL SELECT 4, 402, "printed", timestamp("2022-07-24 10:30:06"), "2022-07-26"
  UNION ALL SELECT 5, 501, "printed", timestamp("2022-07-25 11:13:47"), "2022-07-26"
  UNION ALL SELECT 1, 101, "paid", timestamp("2022-07-16 22:07:32"), "2022-07-26"
  UNION ALL SELECT 1, 102, "paid", timestamp("2022-07-16 23:40:11"), "2022-07-26"
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 201, "paid", timestamp("2022-07-18 07:12:47"), "2022-07-26"
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 202, "paid", timestamp("2022-07-18 08:22:32"), "2022-07-26"
),
selected_trips AS (
  SELECT * FROM trips WHERE run_date = '2022-07-26'
),
selected_receipts AS (
  SELECT * FROM receipts WHERE run_date = '2022-07-26'
),
source_data AS
(
  SELECT 
    t.source_id AS source_id, 
    t.journey_id AS journey_id, 
    t.pickup_time AS pickup_time, 
    t.drop_time AS drop_time, 
    t.is_continue_journey AS is_continue_journey,
    STRUCT(r.fk_id, r.receipt_id, r.state, r.created_at) AS receipt
  FROM selected_trips AS t
  FULL OUTER JOIN selected_receipts AS r 
  ON 
    t.source_id = r.fk_id
    AND (r.created_at >= t.pickup_time 
    AND (t.drop_time IS NULL OR r.created_at <= t.drop_time))
)
SELECT 
  source_id, 
  journey_id, 
  ANY_VALUE(is_continue_journey) AS is_continue_journey,
  ANY_VALUE(pickup_time) AS pickup_time,
  ANY_VALUE(drop_time) AS drop_time, 
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(receipt)) AS receipts 
FROM source_data 
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Actual result (failed to grouping the receipts / requirement no. 3):
[image]

Expected result :
[image]

And another question, is there any efficiency way to query with my case above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix is very simple and is inside `source_data` CTE

instead of

```
t.source_id AS source_id,
```

you should use

```
COALESCE(t.source_id, r.fk_id) AS source_id,
```

as it is in below example

```
source_data AS
(
  SELECT 
    COALESCE(t.source_id, r.fk_id) AS source_id, 
    t.journey_id AS journey_id, 
    t.pickup_time AS pickup_time, 
    t.drop_time AS drop_time, 
    t.is_continue_journey AS is_continue_journey,
    STRUCT(r.fk_id, r.receipt_id, r.state, r.created_at) AS receipt
  FROM selected_trips AS t
  FULL OUTER JOIN selected_receipts AS r 
  ON 
    t.source_id = r.fk_id
    AND (r.created_at >= t.pickup_time 
    AND (t.drop_time IS NULL OR r.created_at <= t.drop_time))
)
```

in this case - output is

[image]